# Misdirected messages in feed

Tags: support, chat, notifications

I just opened up Software Engineering and found 14 messages in my feed from chat on Stack Overflow. The problem is, while I have been in the chat room recently (C#), I haven't typed any messages there in the last few days, and all of the messages addressed to "me" in my feed are actually responses to another person with the nickname "Tom".

Is this something that needs/can be fixed, or should I just change my nickname to something a little less common?

[image: Misdirected Messages]

Comment: You're sure your name is not [Tim](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/132562/158100)?

Comment: No, Tim is my office mate

Comment: Related http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/268351/213575

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is by design. Your username is Tom, so the syntax to ping you in chat is `@Tom`. If someone else also has the username Tom (or a derivative, such as Tommy) then they can *also* be pinged using `@Tom`. Since the system hasn't had any AI upgrades for the past 8 years, it can't tell which one of you it's intended to ping, so it pings *any and all* Toms who are in the room.